# Why doesnt gradle wrapper task get exectuted?

Tags: gradle

I am following this tutorial

http://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/

And I have created a file named build.gradle. It has a task named wrapper defined as follows:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.8'
}
```

I havenot installed gradle in my machine as the site  mentioned above states that gradle shouldnot be installed.However gradle command is not recognized and the wrapper task isn't executed.

Could someone help me how to build projects with gradle wrapper task.

And also how does machine which has no gradle installed recognise gradle command without it being installed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You misunderstood the guide.

Declaring a wrapper task and executing `gradle wrapper` allows creating a lightweight jar file along with windows and Unix shell scripts and some config files, so that other developers getting your project won't have to install gradle. They will get your project, execute `gradlew` at the root of the project (`gradlew` is the windows/unix shell script created by the wrapper task), and this will automatically download and install gradle for them.

But you have to install gradle the classical way to at least be able to run gradle the first time and create the wrapper files. Once that is done, you can use `gradlew`. You can even uninstall gradle and run gradlew: it will re-download it and reinstall it for you. Or you can change the version to 1.9, re-execute the wrapper task, and then use gradlew again and it will download and install the 1.9 version.

See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html for more information about the gradle wrapper.